# svn patch remove folder

Tags: svn, patch

A little background Information:
We'd like to use utilize svn patches in order to keep our two repositories (which have the same structure but exist parallel to each other without physical connection) in sync. The two repositories only contain textual data and are both edited by end users. So These two repositories run out of sync sooner or later. Those changes shall be merged using patches.

The Problem: When I apply a patch that should remove a folder - this folder is not removed in the working copy the patch is applied to (the working of the other repository). The folder even keeps existent in the repository the patch is applied to.

Two questions:

1. Is it a sensible means to use patches to keep the two repos in sync?
2. How can I get the folder in the target repo to be removed as well using a patch?

Comment: Why do not you use svnsync?  Svnsync is the Subversion remote repository mirroring tool. Put simply, it allows you to replay the revisions of one repository into another one: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.ref.svnsync.html

Comment: @IvanJovovic it's http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.replication

Comment: I've edited my question. Both repositories are edited by end users and by using patches those changes shall be merged. By using patches conflict resolution should be possible. Is there a way svnsync can help in that case?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to use SVN in a distributed way, which is going to be difficult no matter how you manage it. Is changing version control systems an option? That's exactly what distributed version control systems are for.

Comment: well, your're right. Changing the version control system is an option. But we heavily depend on externals. We even reference revisions of other folders in the same repository. I am currently investigating on git. At least git submodules don't seem to be a externals equivalent.